# django python password reset email subject with non-english characters

Tags: django, python-3.x

urls.py:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
            email_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset.html',
            html_email_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset.html',
            subject_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset_subject.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
```

In my password_reset_subject.html I have this:
`Восстановление пароля`

But I get this subject when sending a email:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?b?0JLQvtGB0YHRgtCw0L3QvtCy0LvQtdC90LjQtSDQv9Cw0YDQvtC70Y8=?=
```

What do I do?